# Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary format version

Tags: flutter, protocol-buffers

I am trying to generate `protocol buffers` in `flutter` and getting this error:

```
Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary format version
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 7):

1. `flutter pub global deactivate protoc_plugin` or `pub global deactivate protoc_plugin`
2. `flutter pub global activate protoc_plugin`
3. Voila, it upvotes/works again.